# how to run qt key Event in background with window type WindowStaysOnTopHint?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyside6

This my project app for key cast in tutorial and `gui.py` is widget front app code and `main.py` is backend app code

**sources code**

gui.py

```
from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QLocale,
    QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,
    QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor,
    QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient, QIcon,
    QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPainter,
    QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient, QTransform)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QLabel, QSizePolicy, QWidget)

class Ui_keycast(object):
    def setupUi(self, keycast):
        if not keycast.objectName():
            keycast.setObjectName(u"keycast")
        keycast.resize(287, 75)
        self.label_2 = QLabel(keycast)
        self.label_2.setObjectName(u"label_2")
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QRect(9, 30, 269, 16))
        self.label_2.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet(f"""
                                    /*color*/
                                    color: #464d55;
                                    /*font_weight*/
                                    font-weight: bold;
                                    /*font_size*/
                                    font-size: 18px;
                                    """)

        self.retranslateUi(keycast)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(keycast)
    # setupUi
    def retranslateUi(self, keycast):
        keycast.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("keycast", u"keycast", None))
        self.label_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("keycast", u"TextLabel", None))
    # retranslateUi
```

main.py

```
from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QLocale,
    QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,
    QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor,
    QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient, QIcon,
    QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPainter,
    QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient, QTransform,QKeyEvent)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QLabel, QSizePolicy, QWidget,QDialog)
import time
import sys
import threading
# import main_gui
import keypressed_gui
class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        # self.ui = main_gui.Ui_JumpingButtons()
        
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowType.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        # self.setw
        self.ui = keypressed_gui.Ui_keycast()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event) :
        # print(event.keyCombination().keyboardModifiers())
        # print(event.keyCombination().key().name)
        if event.keyCombination().keyboardModifiers() == Qt.KeyboardModifier.ShiftModifier and event.keyCombination().key() == Qt.Key.Key_S:
            self.ui.label_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("keycast", f"Shift + S", None))
            self.ui.label_2.update()
        elif event.keyCombination().keyboardModifiers() == Qt.KeyboardModifier.ShiftModifier:
            self.ui.label_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("keycast", u"Shift", None))
            self.ui.label_2.update()
        elif event.keyCombination().keyboardModifiers() == Qt.KeyboardModifier.ControlModifier:
            self.ui.label_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("keycast", u"Ctrl", None))
            self.ui.label_2.update()
        elif event.keyCombination().keyboardModifiers() == Qt.KeyboardModifier.AltModifier:
            self.ui.label_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("keycast", u"Alt", None))
            self.ui.label_2.update()
        elif event.keyCombination().key() == Qt.Key.Key_Return:
            self.ui.label_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("keycast", u"Enter", None))
            self.ui.label_2.update()
        elif event.keyCombination().key() == Qt.Key.Key_AltGr :
            self.ui.label_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("keycast", u"Alt", None))
            self.ui.label_2.update()
        else:
            self.ui.label_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("keycast", f"{event.text().capitalize()}", None))
        return QWidget().keyPressEvent(event)
    
    def keyReleaseEvent(self, event) :
        # print(event.keyCombination().keyboardModifiers())
        # print(event.keyCombination().key().name)
        time.sleep(0.3)
        self.ui.label_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("keycast", f"", None))

        return QWidget().keyPressEvent(event)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    window = App()
    window.show()
  
    
    exit(app.exec())
```

**Problem**: My Pyside6 application Event is not working in the background and I need window type WindowStaysOnTopHint.

**example** : When I open my application and when my application is selected, it shows me the keyboard key name in the label and when I select another application, my app pauses and does not show the keyboard key name.

**alternative try** : I also tried pynput module but that too is not working. In that I am getting key error because when application pauses then event listener function is not able to be called

**[gif demo link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLy0Q.gif)** :

Answer (score 0):

Application windows do not receive keyboard events when they are not focused. If you are trying to receive those events regardless of the window being or not being focused, you should use Windows api [GetAsyncKeyState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate), which many antivirus apps block apps calling to this api as such apps may be a keylogger.

If you are trying to listen to a global shortcut key event, you can use [RegisterHotKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey).